# Diferenças entre tableView.dequeueReusableCell e UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableviewcell

Boa noite,

Gostaria de saber qual é a diferença entre os parâmetro abaixo, se um é mas eficaz que o outro, menos chances de erro etc. Ao que vejo na prática ambos fazem a mesma coisa. Desde ja agradeço.

1)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cellName”, for: indexPath) 
}
```

2)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cellName") 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O dequeueReusableCell reaproveita recursos que não são utilizados. Ou seja, se você já instanciou 20 células, mas só está mostrando 19, ele vai pegar a 1 que não está sendo usada para instanciar a nova célula que precisa.

Já com o outro método você está sempre instanciando uma nova célula. A documentação recomenda o dequeueReusableCell.

Comment: Obrigado Andreza, pelo esclarecimento não fazia ideia.